# How to merge multiple rows into one row in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, rdbms

can you help me by providing with a sample query showing how to merge multiple rows into one row in sql. Please find the attached images.
[sample input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQl7l.jpg)

Thank you

Here column2 & 3 has same string values t1 and t2,t3 and t4 has same value, and the column 1(parent class) has same names(AAA) for the strings t1,t2,t3,t4. how to merge the multiple rows in to two row
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTNuW.png)

```
select max(cloumn1),cloumn2,cloumn3
from tablename
group by cloumn1;
```

Comment: As per question guideline, please do not post images. Please share us what you've tried and provide DDL + DML commands

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: Why should t1 and t2 be on same row? Same for t3 and t4 as well as t5 and t6. What rule determines these pairings?

Comment: t1 and t2 has same string value ,t3 and t4,t5 and t6 also has same value .i want to compare the column 2 and column 3 group by column 1 . group by command will be used to compare but if the column 1 has lot of same name(AAA) it consider as one name(AAA) . kindly provide an simple query to compare the inputs and get output

Comment: Please do not add clarifications in comments, but edit your question to add further information. You also need, as already said, to tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from 
(select column1,column2,lead(column3) over (order by column1)  as column3 from table1
) a 
where column2 is not null
```

Comment: somehow it gives answer but the query push the value of column3 shows to null. which value has same in column 2 and column 3

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.